# Using GAPI to return list of pages with percentage of views

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

Anyone know how I can return the following information from my Google analytics account using [GAPI](http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/)?

[image: GA account]

Comment: You can get the total page views and compute the percentages yourself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `pagePath` dimension and the `pageviews` metric. Try something like the following:

```
<?php
require 'gapi.class.php';

$gaEmail = 'youremail@email.com';
$gaPassword = 'your password';
$profileId = 'your profile id';

$dimensions = array('pagePath');
$metrics = array('pageviews');
$sortMetric=null;
$filter=null;
$startDate='2011-02-01';
$endDate='2011-02-28';
$startIndex=1;
$maxResults=10000;

$ga = new gapi($gaEmail, $gaPassword);

$ga->requestReportData($profileId, $dimensions, $metrics, $sortMetric, $filter, $startDate, $endDate, $startIndex, $maxResults);

$totalPageviews = $ga->getPageviews();

foreach ($ga->getResults() as $result) {
    $pageviews = $result->getPageviews();
    $percentPageviews = round(($result->getPageviews()/$totalPageviews)*100,2);
    print "$result:$pageviews:$percentPageviews\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: Is there any way with out using gapi.class ?